# Сontent of the directory is only partially bonded in Docker Volumes

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, chmod, chown

I have a Node.JS service running in a Docker container that deploys related Docker containers (Docker-outside-of-Docker) through REST.

The actions sequence (inside the NodeJS container):

1. Create a new folder.
2. Download an archive with a directory structure and files from a git repository.
3. Extract the archive (the target folder is also a volume in NodeJS container).
4. Apply the command `chown -R 0755 .` to the entire extracted content.
5. Edit the `docker-compose.yml` file (nothing special here; all mounted `volumes` are marked as `:rw` - read-write).
6. Run `docker-compose up -d`.

After running `docker-compose up -d`, I noticed that some content from the directories specified in `volumes` does not exist inside the container (`ls -la` - empty folder, but among the unpacked files, I see that this folder is not empty.).

Why does this happen, and how can I solve this issue?

I have already tried:

1. running containers as `root`,
2. granting `privileged` mode,
3. adding `sleep` before `docker-compose up -d`,
4. changing `chmod -R 0777 .`, `chown www-data:www-data`,
5. replacing `mv` with `cp`
6. replacing `:rw` with `:Z`

**UPD**:
Base OS:

```bash
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
```

NodeJS container based on `node:20-slim` (Debian 12)
Children container based on `php:8.2-fpm-alpine3.18`

**UPD**:
Add some more thoughts:
Inside the container I'm creating, my user is www-data. However, in the nodejs container, the www-data user has UID/GID = 33, while in the alpine container, it is UID/GID = 82 (perhaps this is causing a conflict?).
I believe the issue lies somewhere around here, with file permissions.

**UPD**:
I switched from Debian to Alpine in the NodeJS container, but the issue persists.

**UPD**:
When executing `ls -la` inside the container, it is evident that some folders (included in the volumes) have a different user as the owner. Attempting to change the user with `chown -R 82:82 [folder]` results in the error `chown: [folder]: Operation not permitted`.
However, if stop a container and then execute `docker-compose up -d` from the `root` user of the `host machine`, the container starts, and all permissions are correct.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, this post is of very good quality for a first post (which unfortunately, is all too rare these days). Can you please include your Linux distribution info too (`cat /etc/os-release`)? It's possible that it has something to do with SELinux if you are on Fedora or RHEL.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to join the community! Of course, I supplemented my question.

Comment: You should create an [MCVE]. What docker-compose.yml, what volumes, what configuration, what directories, what commands, exactly are you executing? What "docker-outside-of-docker" configuration are you executing - what does it mean exactly, what is docker info output, are you connecting via socket or docker swarm or ssh in DOCKER_HOST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Docker-outside-of-Docker

I suspect the directories you have given to docker-compose are relative to docker-compose file.

You are running on docker *outside*. That means that directories specified with `volumes:` are directories *outside*, they are directories *on the host* where docker daemon is running.

Because `volumes:` by default creates an empty directory, most probably you created a bunch of empty directories on the host running docker demon. Consider using the form `volumes: - type: bind source: /dir target: /dir` so that docker fails with directory not found when directory does not exists as a protection.

Comment: You're right! How did I not think of that! The problem was with the relative path to the folders. Thanks!!!